# Error al intentar ejecutar un CountDownTimer Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

estoy haciendo un pequeño juego en el que tienes un ArrayList con un objeto llamado Palabras. La aplicación consiste en ir recorriendo ese ArrayList e ir mostrando las palabras en Español con distintas palabras en inglés y acertar dicha palabra. Estoy intentando hacer que al finalizar un determinado tiempo esta palabra cambie, la palabra cambia las primeras dos veces, a la que hace una tercera vez la aplicación deja de funcionar. El código que uso es el siguiente: Genero un CountDownTimer para que cuando finalice este sobrescriba los valores del label y de los botones. Gracias por vuestra atención

```java
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(juego){
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnOPC1:
                    if (palabrasInicial.get(n).getPalabraEN().equals(btnOPC1.getText().toString())) {
                        try {
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        correct.start();
                        palabrasInicial.get(n).setAciertos(palabrasInicial.get(n).getAciertos()+1);
                        palabrasIngles.clear();
                        contadorPalabras++;
                        puntuacion++;
                        n++;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Acierto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        try {
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        fail.start();
                        palabrasInicial.get(n).setAciertos(0);
                        palabrasIngles.clear();
                        contadorPalabras++;
                        n++;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fallo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.btnOPC2:
                    if (palabrasInicial.get(n).getPalabraEN().equals(btnOPC2.getText().toString())) {
                        try {
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        correct.start();
                        palabrasInicial.get(n).setAciertos(palabrasInicial.get(n).getAciertos()+1);
                        palabrasIngles.clear();
                        contadorPalabras++;
                        puntuacion++;
                        n++;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Acierto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        try {
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        fail.start();
                        palabrasInicial.get(n).setAciertos(0);
                        palabrasIngles.clear();
                        contadorPalabras++;
                        n++;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fallo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.btnOPC3:
                    if (palabrasInicial.get(n).getPalabraEN().equals(btnOPC3.getText().toString())) {
                        try {
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        correct.start();
                        palabrasInicial.get(n).setAciertos(palabrasInicial.get(n).getAciertos()+1);
                        palabrasIngles.clear();
                        contadorPalabras++;
                        puntuacion++;
                        n++;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Acierto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        try {
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        fail.start();
                        palabrasInicial.get(n).setAciertos(0);
                        palabrasIngles.clear();
                        contadorPalabras++;
                        n++;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fallo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.btnOPC4:
                    if (palabrasInicial.get(n).getPalabraEN().equals(btnOPC4.getText().toString())) {
                        try {
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        correct.start();
                        palabrasInicial.get(n).setAciertos(palabrasInicial.get(n).getAciertos()+1);
                        palabrasIngles.clear();
                        contadorPalabras++;
                        puntuacion++;
                        n++;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Acierto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        try {
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        fail.start();
                        palabrasInicial.get(n).setAciertos(0);
                        palabrasIngles.clear();
                        contadorPalabras++;
                        n++;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fallo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
            }

            if (contadorPalabras == totalPalabras) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                returnIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("listaPalabra",(ArrayList) palabrasInicial);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
                txtPalabra.setText("Has acertado: " + puntuacion + " de " + totalPalabras);
                btnOPC1.setText("");
                btnOPC2.setText("");
                btnOPC3.setText("");
                btnOPC4.setText("");
                juego = false;
            }else{
                GenerarJuego();
            }
        }
    }


    private void GenerarJuego() {

        palabrasUsadas.add(palabrasInicial.get(n));
        palabrasIngles.add(palabrasInicial.get(n).getPalabraEN());

        txtPalabra.setText(palabrasInicial.get(n).getPalabraSP());

        int posCorrecta = rand.nextInt(4);

        switch (posCorrecta) {
            case 0:
                btnOPC1.setText(palabrasInicial.get(n).getPalabraEN());
                btnOPC2.setText(ObtenerPalabra());
                btnOPC3.setText(ObtenerPalabra());
                btnOPC4.setText(ObtenerPalabra());
                break;
            case 1:
                btnOPC1.setText(ObtenerPalabra());
                btnOPC2.setText(palabrasInicial.get(n).getPalabraEN());
                btnOPC3.setText(ObtenerPalabra());
                btnOPC4.setText(ObtenerPalabra());
                break;
            case 2:
                btnOPC1.setText(ObtenerPalabra());
                btnOPC2.setText(ObtenerPalabra());
                btnOPC3.setText(palabrasInicial.get(n).getPalabraEN());
                btnOPC4.setText(ObtenerPalabra());
                break;
            case 3:
                btnOPC1.setText(ObtenerPalabra());
                btnOPC2.setText(ObtenerPalabra());
                btnOPC3.setText(ObtenerPalabra());
                btnOPC4.setText(palabrasInicial.get(n).getPalabraEN());
                break;
        }

        TiempoJuego();
    }

    private void TiempoJuego(){
        new CountDownTimer(tiempoMaximo, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Log.i("tiempoTranscurrido", String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished));
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                GenerarJuego();
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Comment: ¿puedes añadir el error que te da y donde? Para ver más fácil cual puede ser el problema.

Comment: No muestra ningún error en la consola, lo único que hace es que a la tercera vez que ejecuta el GenerarJuego() la aplicación se congela y deja de funcionar. Si quito el CountDownTimer no ocurre esto

Answer (score 0):

Cambia tu contador por este:

```
public class Contador extends CountDownTimer {

    public Contador(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {/////CUANDO SE TERMINA EL CONTEO DEL TIEMPO
        GenerarJuego();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        int segundos = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);///CADA VEZ QUE PASA UN SEGUNDO LLEGA ACA
    }

}
```

Lo declaras como `Contador counter` y lo inicializas así:

```
counter = new Contador(tiempo,1000);
counter.start();
```